# Side by side Operating System

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a PC with MS-W7 installed.  It is 64 bit with a 1Tb hard drive.  Its fast enough and has enough RAM to take on a side installation of UBUNTU.  I understand that when I install UBUNTU, the install program will define another partition on the drive for the UBUNTU OS. So instead of a drive with one 1T partition (C:), I will have a drive with two 500Gb partitions, one for W7 and the other for UBUNTU.

My question:  If I choose to remove either OS for any reason, what happens to the partition that was associated with the removed system.  Does it disappear and I am left with only one half a hard drive or do I get the partition back to use with the remaining OS?

georgebee

Answer (score 1):

If you remove one or the other OS, you can grow the remaining partition using tools such as parted, or several other options that you can find on the web.

-OR- you can just partition the second partition as a secondary drive.